# SQL Server: retrieve unique rows for a specific year but not if they are created earlier

Tags: sql-server, date, count

I have a query that shows a list of products in the year 2018.

I want to view the products if they are created uniquely in 2018 and should not be shown if they have been created earlier in for example in 2017 or so.

Here is my SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products]
(
    [GTIN] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Location] [INT] NULL,
    [Date] [DATETIME] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO Products123(GTIN, Location, Date)
VALUES (12345678911, 1, '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
       (12345678911, 1, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
       (12345678912, 1, '2018-02-01 00:00:00.000'),
       (12345678913, 1, '2018-03-01 00:00:00.000'),
       (12345678914, 1, '2018-03-01 00:00:00.000'),
       (12345678915, 1, '2018-04-01 00:00:00.000'),
       (12345678916, 1, '2018-05-01 00:00:00.000'),
       (12345678917, 1, '2018-06-01 00:00:00.000'),
       (12345678918, 1, '2018-07-01 00:00:00.000');
```

My query:

```
SELECT 
    DATENAME(MONTH, DATE) AS Dato,
    COUNT(DISTINCT GTIN) AS PRODUCTS
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         GTIN, DATE = MIN(DATE)
     FROM     
         Products
     WHERE 
         YEAR(DATE) = '2018' 
         AND YEAR(DATE) NOT IN (2017)
     GROUP BY
         GTIN) d
GROUP BY
    MONTH(DATE), DATENAME(MONTH, DATE)
ORDER BY   
    MONTH(DATE)
```

Result:

```
Dato    |   Products
January |     1
February|     1
April   |     2
May     |     1
June    |     1
July    |     1
```

Expected Result:

```
Dato    |   Products
January |     0
February|     1
April   |     2
May     |     1
June    |     1
July    |     1
```

January should be Zero since the product is already created in 2017 (or earlier) and therefore not unique anymore. Can someone help how retrieve the correct list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
WITH products2018 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM @Products AS p
    WHERE Date >= '2018-01-01'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM @Products AS x
        WHERE GTIN = p.GTIN
        AND Date < '2018-01-01'
    )
)
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, d), COUNT(products2018.GTIN)
FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11)) AS numbers(n)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, n, '2018-01-01')) AS dates(d)
LEFT JOIN products2018 ON YEAR(products2018.Date) = YEAR(d) AND MONTH(products2018.Date) = MONTH(d)
GROUP BY d
ORDER BY d
```

Comment: Hello Salman

What about  DATE = min(DATE)?
I'm actually Getting more values in 2018 and that's wrong, it should be less.

Comment: It seems to work for your posted data. Cannot tell where it is coming from but you can comment out the group by / count(*) to debug.

Comment: I'm applying it to my live data which im working with, the difference is the WHERE Clause has just more sql in it. But the numbers are higher than expected, and yes it does work correctly with the above code, so can't tell what's wrong yet :(

Comment: If my where clause has more sql, then it should be writen in both where clauses in your example  right?
here is an Image of how it looks like: https://prnt.sc/lm280r

Comment: I think you can probably discard everything after 2018 in the not exists query (the only check is that the product did not exist before 2018). But I am not sure.

Comment: I changed my query now, but it seems to run forever when there are more records in the table

Comment: With an `ON` clause like `YEAR(products2018.Date) = YEAR(d) AND MONTH(products2018.Date) = MONTH(d)` I'm not surprised. That isn't SARGable, so for a large data set the table scan is going to take ages,.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a [Calendar Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/) instead, but perhaps this get's you what you are after?

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT CT.CalendarDate,
           CT.CalendarMonth,
           CT.CalendarMonthName,           
           P.GTIN,
           P.[Location],
           P.[Date],
           MIN(P.[date]) OVER (PARTITION BY P.GTIN) AS MinDate
    FROM dbo.CalendarTable CT
         LEFT JOIN dbo.Products P ON CT.CalendarDate = P.[date]
    WHERE CT.CalendarYear IN (2017,2018))
SELECT CTE.CalendarMonth,
       CTE.CalendarMonthName,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN CTE.MinDate > '20180101' THEN CTE.GTIN END) AS Products
FROM CTE
GROUP BY CTE.CalendarMonth,
         CTE.CalendarMonthName
ORDER BY CTE.CalendarMonth;
```